# 'regard' also possible without as?

Tags: grammar

I'm wondering whether the verb 'to regard' can be used without 'as': Is it possible to say "The glottal stop is regarded a consonant" in the sense of "The glottal stop is viewed as/defined as a consonant"? Or do I have to say "The glottal stop is regarded **as** a consonant"? To me (German native speaker) the latter one somehow sounds strange..

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The English word **regard** came to the language with the Norman invasion. It's the French word ***regarder***, "to view or to look at."

It is used synonymously with "viewed," as it appears in your first example:  ***The glottal stop is viewed/regarded as a consonant.***

The word is **similar to, *but not equal to* "consider,"** which means to **think about**, ponder, mull or weigh something, without the element of vision - be it literal or metaphoric.

The idiomatic syntax is different. It needs the "as": ***The Zorboppian language is regarded as incomprehensible by people born without bifurcated tongues."***

Answer (score 3):

It really isn't "regarded" that demands the "as" here. You could say "looked upon as" or "treated as" and the "as" would still be required. The meaning here is that the glottal stop is being treated as if it were a member of the class of consonants (even though it might not fully qualify for membership). So "d" **is** a consonant. The glottal stop is treated **as** a consonant. Thus the "as" is essential to the meaning of the sentence, and has nothing really to do with "regarded".

Comment: That's a really interesting point, I haven't thought about that. So could you think of any case in which 'regard' could be used without 'as'?

Comment: "I went up the mountain to regard the view." A bit archaic, but otherwise idiomatic.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.